# Is existing a python built-in function doing the opposite of 'itertools.compress()'? (i.e. inserting multiple element in a list or an iterator)

Tags: python, insert, python-itertools

`itertools.compress()` filter elements based on their index.
I would like to do the opposite. Starting from:

- a 1st list (or an iterable)
- a 2nd list of elements to add in the 1st list
- the list of indexes where to add them in the 1st list (as if it has not been modified already by insertion of a previous element from 2nd list)

This approach needs to assume that elements in my 2nd list are already sorted between them.

Translating this into dummy python code, I am looking for a built-in function (looking for speed) that does this.

```py
import numpy as np
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase

# 1st list: 10 items (int only)
size_exist = 10 #1_000
exist = list(np.random.randint(1_000, size=size_exist))

# 2nd list: 3 items (letters to identify them more easily from items of 1st list)
size_new = 3
new = [choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(size_new)]

# Indexes where to insert elements of 2nd list.
#indexes_new = list(np.random.randint(1_000, size=size_new))
indexes_new = [3,3,4]

# Dummy code
def insert(exist:list, new:list, indexes: list):
    # Doing a copy here as I measured with %timeit,
    # and legacy insert keeps the initial list expanding.
    exist2 = exist.copy() 
    delta_index = 0
    for new_item, index in zip(new, indexes):
        exist2.insert(index+delta_index, new_item)
        delta_index+=1
    return exist2
```

Result

```py
insert(exist, new, indexes_new)
Out[56]: [332, 281, 456, 'c', 't', 397, 'p', 196, 315, 130, 901, 818, 509]
```

Thanks for any ideas!
Bests

Comment: I don't know about a built-in function but if there is no such function, try reverse `new` and `indexes`. That makes insertion easier as it removes the need for the additional `delta_index`.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your comment. I mean, I understand it would be nicer if we could get rid of `delta_index`, but I don't see how I can get the 'dynamic index', that corresponds to the growing `exist`. Currently, the definition requires the indexes based on `exist` at start. I could possibly ask `indexes` corresponding to `exist` once all elements have been inserted, but already, the user is then in charge of doing a loop for that. And for an index that corresponds to the dynamic state of `exist`, the user would actually write the same function as the one I defined.

Comment: To clarify: you could rewrite your for-loop in the following way: `for new_item, index in zip(reversed(new), reversed(indexes)): exist2.insert(index, new_item)`. This works only if the indexes are ordered. Explanation: If you start inserting at the highest index in indexes, the lower indexes in `exist2` remain untouched. Hence, you don't have to maintain `delta_index`.

Comment: yes, thanks, I understand. Yes, I think I can enforce using ordered indexes. thanks, this is interesting!